# mongodb aggregation multiple lookup with conditions

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 3 collection.

```js
db.a.insert([
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb11105e8f41"), "db_type":b, "number" : 1},
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb11105e8f42"), "db_type":c, "number" : 2},
])

db.b.insert([
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb11105e8f43"), "number" : 1, "value" : "111"},
])

db.c.insert([
  { "_id" : ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb11105e8f44"), "number" : 2, "value" : "222"},
])
```

I want to make a lookup query that gets values from each collection according to db_type.

What should I do in this case?

result :

```json
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb11105e8f41"), "db_type" : b, "number" : 1, "value" : "111"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b56989172ebcb11105e8f42"), "db_type" : c, "number" : 2, "value" : "222"}
```

clogged part...

```js
db.getCollection('a').aggregate([
    {
        "$lookup":{
            "from":         "b" or "c", // I want to give condition here.
            "localField":   "number",
            "foreignField": "number",
            "as":           "result"
        }
    },
])
```

Comment: you can make use of `unionWith` https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unionWith/

Comment: lookup doesn't allow expression  on the `"from"` it needs just a string the collection name. So you cant dynamically decide while query runs on server. If you know the possible values before sending the query i think ray's answer or something simlar with `$facet`, its the best you can get. (facet maybe slower but simpler query i think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, as you have only 2 cases `b` and `c` to lookup from. You can simply do 2 separate lookups and use `$setUnion` to group the results together.

```js
db.a.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "b",
      "let": {
        db_type: "$db_type",
        number: "$number"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$db_type",
                    "b"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$number",
                    "$number"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "bLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "c",
      "let": {
        db_type: "$db_type",
        number: "$number"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$db_type",
                    "c"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$number",
                    "$number"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "cLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "allLookup": {
        "$setUnion": [
          "$bLookup",
          "$cLookup"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VcMqTQAOCNg) for your reference.